# Make a Python Program save the changes it makes to itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How would I make it so it saves the changes to the dictionary? It will be able to add a definition then it will be able to be exited then still keep that definition

```
words = {
    "orange": "naranja",
    "hello": "hola",
    "bye": "adiós",
    "red": "rojo",
    "blue": "azul",
    "yellow": "amarillo",
    "purple": "púrpura",
    "green": "verde",
    "white": "blanco",
    "black": "negro",
    "Ethan": "Yeet"
}
while 1 == 1:
    tt = input("What would you like to translate? (Only write in lowercase and type EXIT to quit) ")
    if str(tt) in words:
        print(tt + " is " + words.get(tt, "Not in dictionary"))
    elif str(tt) == "EXIT":
        break
    else:
        atd = input("Would you like to add " + str(tt) + " to our dictionary? Y/N ")
        if atd == "Y" or atd == "y":
            d = input("What does it translate to? ")
            d = str(d)
            tt = str(tt)
            words.update({tt: d})
            print(tt + " is "+ words.get(tt, "What"))
            continue
        elif str(atd) == "EXIT":
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "saves changes to the dictionary?" Technically you're already doing that with `words.update({tt: d})`.

Comment: @JohnPerry Sounds like the question is about persisting those changes to a file.

Comment: @DavidZ Those were my thoughts, too, but in that case he needs to read and write.

Comment: (In more senses than one. ;-))

Comment: I need to close the file and the updates to stay.

Comment: I need to add to my dictionary then close it and reopen it and it to still be there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSON to store your data in a file, reading the data in when you open your Python file.

**my_script.py**

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    words = json.load(f)

#Do some things with your data here - maybe add some new values...

#Write updated data back to file.
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(words, f)
```

**data.json:**

```
{
    "orange": "naranja",
    "hello": "hola",
    "bye": "adiós",
    "red": "rojo",
    "blue": "azul",
    "yellow": "amarillo",
    "purple": "púrpura",
    "green": "verde",
    "white": "blanco",
    "black": "negro",
    "Ethan": "Yeet"
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. How have you implemented this in your code?